# How do you optimize query performance on marketplace shared views in snowflake? Note that incremental materialization probably would not work

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working with data from Snowflake Marketplace, these are large multi-billion record tables.

I have two conflicting needs: speed & up-to-date data

I am able to have up-to-date data by working exclusively with views - meaning the data is up to date from the vendor's perspective at the moment I make a query. However, performance is terrible (the vendor does not cluster their tables the way I would do it)

I can also materialize copies of the tables with my chosen cluster keys. This works great for performance, but it introduces a 10-20h lag every time the tables are updated - which is not good.

My main issue is that this data is "changed" all the time. Ie current and historical values are updated by the vendor in-place (not append). This makes incremental runs almost impossible.

Does Snowflake have any feature that could help in this context?

Comment: Does your vendor cluster the table at all? With frequent in place updates, I am not sure why they would even have clustering in place

Comment: You might be right. I think they cluster the tables on internal only PK that have no meaning in the context of the data I have access to.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that it's a table, not a view that they're sharing. You can request permission from the vendor of this data to be able to place a stream on their table. Once you have a stream on their table, you'll get all the rows you need to complete a synchronization of their table changes with your local copy. This should reduce the 10-20h lag because without setting a stream on their side you'll wind up doing full refreshes. This approach will allow you to handle incremental changes.

When you try to create a stream on a shared table, unless you've already arranged it with the vendor or the vendor has already enabled this for another share consumer, you may get this message:

> SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on stream
> source without CHANGE_TRACKING enabled 'MY_TABLE'

This just means the sharing vendor must enable change tracking on their side. On the sharing account side:

```
alter table MY_TABLE set change_tracking = true;
```

As soon as they make that change, any and all sharing consumers will be able to create a stream on the table:

| status |
| --- |
| Stream MY_STREAM successfully created. |

Comment: Great idea. These concepts are new to me, any guide you can share?

Comment: I reached out to the vendor btw, I've upvoted you and will accept the answer if it works.

Comment: `These concepts are new to me, any guide you can share?` The staff in Snowflake Education found my blog post on streams and told me they're using the script and explanation in their training classes. I haven't updated it with the latest feature additions, but it should still be a good basic primer. Change tables are newer but work more or less the same way.
https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2020/01/12/snowflake-streams-made-simple/